# what does "inkscape:" in .SVG mean?

Tags: xml, svg, inkscape

I know this is trivial but hopefully this proves to be helpful to others aside from just myself.

I keep finding this attribute in the .SVG I am working on: "inkscape:". What does it mean? Then abstracting it out one level what does "anything:" mean when declared as an attribute of a .SVG? eg.

```
inkscape:lblTemplate="{align:Right,attr:get,tag:tag,type:Good}"     zoomAndPan="magnify" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" inkscape:vyplnStroke="txtcolor" xmlns:rtda="http://www.itris.fr/2003/animation" contentStyleType="text/css" id="text0243" version="1.0" width="100" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" inkscape:opac="ver;1;1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" inkscape:textik="max.toFixed(dp)" viewBox="0 0 100 300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" inkscape:componentData="{name:B - T Bar,desc:Bottom - Top Bar,author:mySCADA Team,uniqueID:0348f7cec3,list:[{variableName:tag,name:tag,desc:Tag,value:tag,type:0},{variableName:min,name:min,desc:Min,value:0,type:2},{variableName:max,name:max,desc:Max,value:100,type:2},{variableName:color1,name:color-low,desc:Low color,value:#FFFF00,type:4},{variableName:color2,name:color-norm,desc:Normal color,value:#00FF00,type:4},{variableName:color3,name:color-high,desc:High color,value:#FF0000,type:4},{variableName:txtcolor,name:,desc:Text color,value:#000000,type:4},{variableName:TH1,name:treshold1,desc:1st treshold,value:25,type:2},{variableName:TH2,name:treshold2,desc:2nd treshold,value:75,type:2},{variableName:label,name:label,desc:Label,value:Label,type:1},{variableName:fsize,name:fsize,desc:Font size,value:12,type:2},{variableName:dp,name:,desc:No. of decimal places,value:1,type:2}]}"
```

or

```
inkscape:vypln="txtcolor"
```

Both above examples are inline with the  tag, as in before the ">" in .

Comment: Might be some meta-data for the Inkscape application: http://inkscape.org/. You already tagged the question with `inkscape`, have a look at the tag description! http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inkscape/info

Comment: It's the namespace for non-standard SVG extensions added by the Inkscape application. The result is a valid XML document that can still be partially rendered by a non-Inkscape compliant renderer.

Comment: thanks halfer! and Felix I know what Inkscape is, I wanted to know what inkscape: means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the attribute is within an XML namespace. It is a way of extending the definition of an XML schema without changing the original, that is, maintaining compatibility, i.e. other programs may ignore those attributes.

If you look at the top of the file you'll see a more complete specification of what namespace that "inkscape:" prefix refers to.

In this case, it is obviously some extension related to the Inkscape SVG-editing program.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that it extends the functionality of a .SVG particularly when the .SVG is opened with Inkscape or similar, while making sure it is not ONLY compatible with Inkscape. 

Is it just extra instructions on how to draw the .SVG?

Comment: Something like that. Specifically, the part which says which namespace does "inkscape:" refer to, is this `xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"`, which is a namespace declaration. So, if another prefix, say "ink:" was used, which was defined in the same way `xmlns:ink="...`, then the document would have the same interpretation, even though it would be a few bytes shorter.

Comment: got it! Thanks @Migle. In addition to that if anyone else had the same question what helped me is finding out that a namespace in general is a set (space) of attribute names (eg. height, color, stroke etc.) that you may want to use in a 'different way'... well in which different way? that question is answered in the file you link to in xmlns:namespacename="this is the link im talking about".